# About the creation of a subdomain on cPanel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

About the creation of a subdomain on cPanel, do you advise me to create the directory inside public_html or outside?

How to decide where?

Comment: Still here? Let me know the results.

Answer (score 1):

Create the directory for your **subdomains** & **addon** domains outside the **Public_html** folder is the safest one because its only the solution for the directories got deleted accidentally while updating the primary domain.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this carefully.

You can create the subdomain with the public_html directory if you want your main website files to be viewed by the subdomain. But, if you will delete the subdomain, the public_html directory will be deleted. So, using your subdomain in a directory different than public_html is **safer**.

Secondly, you will need to configure the DNS of the domain if it is not configured automatically, which will result in the subdomain not working.

If in case the subdomain created is not working:
Go to the DNS section of your domain, and create a new CNAME record mostly like this:

```
Host                                   IP (Points to)    TTL
(yoursubdomain with/without domain)    @                 600
```

Also, if you have any trouble with cPanel, you should ask about it at https://forums.cpanel.net for more assistance.